# Modal images popup on top of page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I found this code for image popping up on click, but I want to make it for more than one image. So I tried to change the element(myImg) from ID to Class so I can use smaller code for the page but as soon as I change the ID to Class to code stops to work. I putted the edited version of the code that doesn't work. When it was working when I clicked on the image it popped up in front of the page. When I changed from ID to Class when I click the image nothing happens.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>

  <body>
    <img class="myImg" src="../../content/images/Photography/8bа.jpg" alt="Trolltunga, Norway" width="300" height="200">

    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
      <div id="caption"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

CSS:

```
.myImg {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.myImg:hover { opacity: 0.7; }

.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 1000px;
}

#caption {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
}

.modal-content, #caption {    
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
  to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {transform:scale(0)} 
  to {transform:scale(1)}
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .modal-content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Javascript:

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a 
caption
var img = document.getElementsByClassName('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = this.src;
  captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Please define "doesn't work": what happens and how is this different from what you expect? (Update the *question* please, don't use a comment.)

Comment: Done. I hope is better explained now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName('myImg');` returns an array of nodes, so you need to add the click event to the first node `img[0]` in the array:

**EDIT:** Added support for handling multiple images

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var imgs = document.getElementsByClassName('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");

for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
  imgs[i].addEventListener('click', e => {
      modal.style.display = "block";
      modalImg.src = e.target.src;
      captionText.innerHTML = e.target.alt;
    });
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.myImg {
border-radius: 5px;
cursor: pointer;
transition: 0.3s;
}

.myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

.modal {
display: none; /* Hidden by default */
position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%; /* Full width */
height: 100%; /* Full height */
overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}


.modal-content {
margin: auto;
display: block;
width: 80%;
max-width: 1000px;
}


#caption {
margin: auto;
display: block;
width: 80%;
max-width: 700px;
text-align: center;
color: #ccc;
padding: 10px 0;
height: 150px;
}


.modal-content, #caption {    
-webkit-animation-name: zoom;
-webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
animation-name: zoom;
animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
from {transform:scale(0)} 
to {transform:scale(1)}
}


.close {
position: absolute;
top: 15px;
right: 35px;
color: #f1f1f1;
font-size: 40px;
font-weight: bold;
transition: 0.3s;
 }

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
color: #bbb;
text-decoration: none;
cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
.modal-content {
    width: 100%;
}
}
```

```html
<img class="myImg" src="../../content/images/Photography/8bа.jpg" 
 alt="1) Trolltunga, Norway" width="300" height="200" />
 <img class="myImg" src="../../content/images/Photography/8bа.jpg" 
 alt="2) Trolltunga, Norway" width="300" height="200" />
 <img class="myImg" src="../../content/images/Photography/8bа.jpg" 
 alt="3) Trolltunga, Norway" width="300" height="200" />

 <div id="myModal" class="modal">
 <span class="close">&times;</span>
 <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
 <div id="caption"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: That fixed part of the problem. The code started to work again for the Image with CLASS="myImg", but when I add images with the same class it doesn't work for them(nothing happens OnClick), It works only  for the first one.

Comment: @ValeriKarageorgiev yes because you are only targeting the first image. Can you not add a unique class to each image? If not then you'll have to keep track of the index of which image you clicked. I didn't see this use case in your example.

Comment: I will try to remove the class. But after I do this I am not shure what I have to change in the script.

Comment: @ValeriKarageorgiev Updated the script for you. It should now handle multiple images as long as they have the `myImg` class